# How to restrict same images drop on the specific target

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

I have a few problem regarding drag and drop. The process run drag and drop run perfectly. I'm developing an application where the user can drag and drop sweets out from the jar. When the ACTION_DROP detect the jar layout, it will increase the value (max is 10), the value will decrease when the the sweets drop into the rack. 
[image]

The problem is that, when I drop the sweet on the same layout, it keeps increasing/decreasing until the value reaches its maximum/minimum number. What can i do to avoid this problem?

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {


    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) { 
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            // do nothing
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            // v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            // v.setBackgroundDrawable(answerShape);
            // v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            // // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

            Log.i("drop", "Id First :" + view.getId());
            Log.i("drop", "Id Second :" + v.getId());
            Log.i("value", "Value :" + view.getContentDescription());

            owner.removeView(view);

            if(v.getId()==R.id.jaroval)
            {
                RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                value++;
                sound();
            }
            else{
                GridLayout container = (GridLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                value--;
                sound();
            }
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            // v.setBackgroundDrawable(answerShape);
            // v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        default:
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi use this sample code 
activity_mail.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pinkLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:background="#FF8989"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dragtext" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/yellowLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:background="#FFCC00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

2> MainActivity.java

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener,
        OnDragListener {
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.textView1).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.pinkLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.yellowLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
    int action = dragevent.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        Log.e(LOGCAT, "Drag event started");
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        Log.e(LOGCAT, "Drag event entered into " + layoutview.toString());
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        Log.e(LOGCAT, "Drag event exited from " + layoutview.toString());
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        Log.e(LOGCAT, "Dropped");
        View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        owner.removeView(view);
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
        container.addView(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        Log.e(LOGCAT, "Drag ended");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

In this example ,DragEvent.ACTION_DROP condition real view is remove first and add new view to parent view and than after that is visible.
So you are copy new view in side gridview and remove from sweet view layout.

I hope you are understand this example and implement in your code easily.

Comment: Thanks sir, but my drag and drop function is working. I have problem with the counting, the number keep increasing/decreasing when i drop on the same layout.